# SQL data returned in excel and needs auto formating in excel

Tags: sql, excel, formatting

I have a ODBC connection to a SQL database, which is returning my data to row A10 and down depending on a date criteria inserted into cell A1 and B1, along with a submit button.

What I would like to do is depending on the number of rows, so needs to be dynamic, could the rows be formatted with cell borders. That's all, simple, but checked on here and cant find anything like that. I don't want to use excel tables, unless I really have too.

Cheers

Comment: You could set the range as an excel table and it should automatically extend the range based on the data.

Comment: I ideally don't want to use excel table - however if that is the only way. How do you set the range as an excel table from a vb script

Comment: To clarify are you using a vbscript or using VBA within excel?

Comment: Hi bee - Yes I am using VBA Project in excel, assigned to a module and button in excel to fresh and connect to the sql database

Comment: OK.  You're already doing VBA so have a look at the link https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm which can help you find the last cell in a range. You will then need to assign the whole range to an object variable and then use the format properties of the object to change the format.  I suggest the forum VBAX (http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/index.php ) they are quite helpful with VBA and more useful for beginners than SO.